# Django "Dependency on unknown app" error even though the app folder exists

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run manage.py runserver or manage.py makemigrations, but I'm getting an error when I do. The error is: ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: backend.

Here's the full error message:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:package-backend benhsu$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 57, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 243, in build_graph
    parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 168, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on unknown app: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: backend
```

"backend" is the app I'm working on, and you can see in my folder that it exists. Here's my folder structure:

[image]

Here's the relevant part of my settings.py file:

```
# Application definition

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'backend'
)
```

I don't understand why it's not working since the backend app exists in my folder.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: try this `./manage.py makemigrations backend`

Comment: I can't seem to execute that command. When I do, I get the error:

Comment: Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:package-backend benhsu$ ./manage.py makemigrations backend -bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied

Comment: Check if you have: `backend/migrations/__init__.py`

Answer (score 3):

Did you trying to use `custom User` model since `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'` ?

So You have to try like this.

```
 ./manage.py makemigrations backend
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#s-custom-fields

Comment: When I try that I get:

Comment: Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:package-backend benhsu$ ./manage.py makemigrations backend
-bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied

Comment: Even when I do "python3 manage.py makemigrations backend" I get the dependency on unknown app error

Comment: comment `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'` in settings and try

Comment: I got this error while going through Test Driven Development with Python. @itzmeontv 's suggestion got it working again.

Comment: Removing AUTH_USER_MODEL is probably NOT what you want, it will cause Django to use the default user model instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error with a custom `user` app.

I deleted:

- all `migrations` folders
- all `*.pyc` files
- all `__pycach__` directories
- my sql lite db

then I ran

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

And that did the trick